# can not find C/C++ in project properties

Tags: .net, c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am following a tutorial and one of the steps its asking is to go to my projects properties and click on c/c++ and add a path to "Additional Include Directories" property. I am using visual C++ Express Edition 2008. the tutorial is using the same thing. Is there away to get this or an alternative ??

This is my screen
[image]

This is tutorials screen 
[image]

Comment: Try adding a c++ source file (.cpp-file) and see if the menu appears.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't have the C++ compiler options until you're actually using the C++ compiler.  In this case, you don't have a .cpp file.  So just add one and the compiler options will appear.

Comment: Learn something new every day!

Comment: I am having a lot of c++ files still I see only Configuration Properties->General, Debugging, VC++ Directories, NMake. No C/C++, Linker, Manifest tool etc. BTW, it is a driver. Is it bcoz of that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a definitive solution, because I've seen so many cases ( when I grade my students' homework ).
I've never made such a case on my own, but many of my students' homework appeared to have that case of missing c/c++ category.
In those cases, build succeeded but executables not generated.
Adding new c source file to the project will display the c/c++ category, but if you remove the source file from the project, then c/c++ category will go away again.
It was not .vcxproj file problem.
I think for some reason, VS failed to recognize the source as a c source file.

So, my solution is;
Select the source file of the project in solution explorer, then right click to select the property of the c source file.
Then select 'Item Type' to 'C/C++ compiler'.
Then c/c++ category will appear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After adding .cpp file it may not show C/C++ in the project's properties. This is because value of "Configuration Type" is "Utility". Change this value to .dll and apply. Now you can see C/C++ in Configuration Properties.
[image]

Comment: Where do I change this?

Comment: Under "Configuration Properties" I only have "Configuration"

Comment: Visual Studio 2022: Configuration Properties — General — Project Defaults — Configuration Type

Answer (score 0):

Or if you copied cpp files to a newly created project, you need to right click on the src folder and select "Include in Project", only then will visual studio consider them part of the project and show C++ in properties.

(If you don't see "src" in your project, make sure to toggle "show all files" in the Solution Explorer options.)