# Unable to view C/C++ section under configuration properties in Visual Studio 2013/2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

When I go to Project->Properties, I'm unable to see the "C/C++" section under configuration properties. Additionally, I've researched the issue and have come across the following links:

[can not find C/C++ in project properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309091/can-not-find-c-c-in-project-properties)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9498435d-8dc6-4056-b307-73960409cac7/missing-cc-option-under-property-pages-configuration-properties?forum=vcgeneral

https://superuser.com/questions/259668/visual-c-2010-express-no-c-c-folder-showing-up-in-project-property-pages

In all of them, they suggest to add a cpp source file to the project and the section should appear. However, my issue is that the project already has multiple *.cpp files in it. If I add a few more source files, the section still did not appear.

The codebase in question can be found [here](https://github.com/Razish/japp) if you would like to try for yourself. I've tried with VS 2013 Professional and 2015 Enterprise. Is there some arcane setting that needs to be set for it to appear?

[image: No C/C++ section under config properties]
[image: Multiple c++ files]

Comment: In your .vcxproj you have `<keyword>MakeFileProj</keyword>`. Check if removing that helps.

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by removing the following line in the .vcxproj:

```
<ConfigurationType>Makefile</ConfigurationType>
```

From this [MSDN documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx), it seems that the options are only available to the "Application" configuration type (AFAIK)? Here's the excerpt.

> Application (.exe), displays linker toolset (C/C++ Compiler, MIDL, Resource Compiler, Linker, BSCMake, XML Web Service Proxy Generator, custom build, prebuild, prelink, postbuild events).

Comment: It's also changable without editing .vcxproj directy - from Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type

Answer (score 0):

In latest update of VS 2013 and Visual studio 2015 by default VC++ would not be installed. So first make sure you have installed VC++. You can check it via creating simple new win32 console application.

If VC++ is installed then create any new project and check whether C++ section is available or not in your new project properties. If C++ section available in your new project properties means there must be an issue with your existing project settings in your current project.

Comment: It is an issue with the existing project settings. I am able to see the section in a new project.